# What is "Agnihotra"?

Tags: mantras, homam

This Wikipedia [Link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnihotra)  provides only one line  about Agnihotra.  Its said that Agnihotra is very simple and easy , We  can do Agnihotra at home on daily basis .So i would  like to know more about Agnihotra in short  like -:

**What is the procedure , what things we need to perform Agnihotra?**

**What's the timing and the mantra's associeated with Agnihotra?**

Comment: @Swiftpushkar--You should have a small copper agni kundam. Fire woods, branches of people tree, ghee, darvis  [wooden  spoon for pouring ghee] camphor to light the fire initially, darba grass  to be put on four sides, some flowers to keep on homa kundam.  Timing--Within 11 AM .  After taking bath this should be done. Mantras will post a comment tomorrow. For any doubts  will give a mail id and phone number  of a person who is doing agnihothra daily in Chennai.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan - But is it dried cow dung  or wood that is to be used in Agnihotra?

Comment: If you get dried cow dung it is better. You have to use both. Just do for 10 minutes daily.

Comment: Before commencing agnihothra kindly get the upadesa from a guru or a person who do agnihothra daily. That is what elders used to say. The current jeer of ahoila mutt was a agnihothra in purvasrama.

Comment: @swiftpushkar--agnihothra is a sacred one. The elders in our house used to say get proper advise before commencing from a right person.46th pontiff of ahobila mutt [current jeer] before taking charge was doing agnihothra daily in his house. It is a fact not a story.

Comment: @swiftpushkar--Vedic Wisdom Homam Group conducts free homam classes every Saturday and Sunday. The fifth batch starts from July16 and is open to all. No prior knowledge of Sanskrit is required.

The duration of the course is 18 hours (2 hours per class).Venue:P4, B-block, Tulip Gardens Apartments, Krishna Nagar 2nd Street, Rajakilpakkam. Those interested can call Srini at 9283111113
Call in this number and inquire about agnihothra. Not having his mail id.

Comment: @swiftpushkar--Will get the  mail id and inform u

Comment: As I am doing homams a little bit I know about agnihothra. That is what I shared. Big homams like sudarsana homam we are doing which lasts for 6 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Agnihotra is a process that uses healing fire to purify the
>   surroundings. The fire is prepared through a specific process, which
>   is performed twice a day – during the sunrise and the sunset. In other
>   words, Agnihotra is a ‘vedic yagna’ or a ritual that is mentioned in
>   the Vedas, which is followed by the class of “Nambudiri Brahmins” of
>   Kerala in India. There has been a worldwide increase in awareness
>   about the innumerable effects of Agnihotra homam in the recent past.
>
> The procedure of Agnihotra incorporates preparation with Agnihotra kit
>   a small fire using cakes of cow dung in a tiny copper pyramid of
>   specific shape and size into which ghee and grains of rice are added
>   during the sunrise and the sunset. The significant part of the whole
>   process is the two mantras that are chanted while adding the ghee and
>   rice grains to the special fire, which is what is supposed to enhance
>   the power of the process. The entire process is said to release
>   tremendous energy in the surroundings.
>
> **Working of Agnihotra**
>
> - The copper and its pyramid shape generate negative ions, which clear    the air of various hazardous particles.
> - Since cow dung is a natural and potential disinfectant, it reduces    bacteria in the air and surroundings.
> - Pure ghee is a natural detox agent. Since ghee does not alter in    weight or properties when burnt under appropriate conditions, it
>     dissolves the toxic contents in the air.
> - Rice offers a balance of ying-yang effect and releases several    ethereal oils during combustion, thereby setting off chemical
>     reactions.
> - The chanting of the Agnihotra mantra in Sanskrit during the sunrise    and the sunset creates resonance in line with the biorhythm and
>     activates special vibrations. According to Vedas, mantras have
>     potential effect on every aspect of human life and surroundings.
>     There are specific mantras that can act upon specific aspects of
>     human life.
> - Finally, the smoke from the homa binds harmful radiations in the air    and neutralizes their radioactive effect.
>
> [image]
>
> **Agnihotra Process Step by Step**
>
> - Copper Pyramid – small size
> - Dried cow dung
> - Clarified and unsalted pure ghee from cow’s butter
> - Unpolished rice – 2 pinches
> - Timetable with exact time of the sunrise the and sunset
>
> **Process:**
>
> - Ignite the fire at the appropriate time (5 minutes before the sunrise/sunset).
> - Take a few grains of unpolished rice in your left hand and apply a few drops of pure ghee to the rice and mix well.
> - Divide the smeared rice into two portions.
>
> **Morning Agnihotra**
>
> At the exact time of sunrise, chant the morning mantra as follows:
>
> ```
>        Sooryaya Swaaha Suryaya Idan Na mama |
>
>        Prajapataye Swaaha Prajapataye Idan Na mama |
> ```
>
> Immediately after you utter swaaha in the first mantra, take one
>   portion of the rice (one pinch) and offer it to the fire. Similarly,
>   after you utter swaaha in the second mantra, offer the remaining rice
>   to the fire.
>
> **Evening Agnihotra**
>
> At the exact time of sunset, chant the mantra as follows:
>
> ```
>        Agnaye Swaaha Agnaye Idam Na mama|
>
>        Prajapataye Swaaha Prajapataye Na mama|
> ```
>
> Similar to the morning process, immediately on uttering swaaha both
>   times, offer the two portions of rice mixture respectively to the
>   fire.

[Source](http://zigverve.com/lifestyle/living-spirituality/agnihotra-mantras-process-effects-of-performing-agnihotra-homam/)

Comment: Nice answer but it is not necessary to have havan kund made of this or that material, in ancient times they used mango tree wood (samidha) and yajna kund was kind of sand made, ghee, samagri and water , you are good to go

Comment: Not entirely true but good answer.

Comment: @Rishi From Ancient time these rules are followed strictly.

Answer (score 9):

I hope the following answer conveys the idea of why it is non trivial to answer your question briefly. Your question is akin to asking "What is the procedure to worship the Lord" or "What is the procedure to perform Sandhyavandana". Nothing short of an elaborate manual would suffice to answer your question. I hope the linked videos of Agnihotra practice demonstrate this.

*There is a lot of incorrect information being spread about Agnihotra. Much of what can be found on the internet or YouTube about Agnihotra on neo-Hindu websites is pure fiction.*

**It is incorrect that it is simple/easy to perform Agnihotra (well, simple/easy is a perspective). It is also incorrect that anyone and everyone can perform Agnihotra.** Agnihotra is a Vedic ceremony/lifestyle and thus comes with all rules/eligibility criteria that Vedic yajnas do. For an example of Agnihotra in Shukla Yajur Veda see the recording of [Ram Prasad Gautam of Nepal](https://youtu.be/vZIyH9wBW54). For an example of Agnihotra in Krishna Yajur Veda, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D5QXAXbjsE&t=837s) and related recordings of the fortnighly sacrifices.

I am going to describe Agnihotra in the context of Brahmin performers. It is possible that Kshatriyas and Vaishyas also are eligible to perform it, but I only know about the eligibility of Brahmins.

A Brahmin student after completing his basic Vedic education (learning to recite the text of his own recension/shakha) tend specialize one of the following paths:

1. further studies in Vedic recitation (advanced modes of recitation like Krama and Ghana),
2. further studies in one or more Sastras: Tarka, Vyakarana, Mimamsa, Vedanta, Dharma texts, Agama, Veda Bhashya
3. further studies in Grihya Sutras and the performance of upAdhyAya or paurohitya (performing domestic rituals for families).
4. further studies in Mimamsa/Srauta followed by a commitment to the lifelong performance of Agnihotra.

These four paths are not mutually exclusive. E.g. one can learn advanced Vedic recitation, learn Tarka Sastra and perform Agnihotra while also being a family priest. However it is  not typical for people to do so.

There are other eligibility criteria to pursue the path of Agnihotra. E.g. One must be married with a living wife (the ceremony is jointly performed) and must have a son (jAta-putraH). His hair must still be predominantly black (kRRiShNakeshI).

> jātaputraḥ kṛṣṇakeśī agnīnādadhīta (śabara on jaiminī 1.3.2-3)

He must either be an eldest son, OR his older brothers must all be practising Agnihotrins, OR he must receive permission from his older brothers to kindle his fires before them.

Agnihotra is performed in three fires: Garhaptya, Ahavaniya and Dakshinagni. The setting up the the three fires is performed in a ritual called agnyAdhAna. Once lit, the fires must not burn out until the sacrificer, or his wife dies. In practice, the  Dharma Sastras allow some flexibility about this for exceptional circumstances, OR old age.

Performing daily agnihotra is accompanied by the fortnightly, monthly and quarterly yajnas. Having performed this for one year, the performer becomes eligible to perform advanced Vedic Yajnas like the Seven Soma sacrifices.

**I would guess that there are less than one hundred living performers of traditional Agnihotra today!** Some Kalivarjya texts prohibit the performance of the Agnihotra in the Kali Yuga.

Source:

1. David Knipe's monograph - "Vedic Voices: Intimate Narratives of a Living Andhra Tradition"
2. The 'Kalivarjyas' or 'Prohibitions in the Kali Age' by Batuknath Bhattacharya.

Comment: Nice answer and explanation.What I mean by anyone  and everyone is among dvijas only and without need of Guru or guide etc.

Comment: Your premise that it may be possible to do Agnihotra without a Guru or guide is incorrect. As I have indicated in the answer, even if you (1) isolate the Agnihotra mantras from the rest of the Vedas, and (2) the Agnihotra procedure from the rest of the Mimamsa/Srauta Sutras, and (3) assuming you meet all other eligibility criteria,  you still need to master the mantras by learning it from a teacher (Vedic mantras have intonation).  Continuing in next comment.

Comment: A mantra will only be fruitful if it is chanted with (1) faith in the mantra itself, (2)  devotion towards the deity that is addressed by the mantra, and (3) remembering the Guru who (having himself attained mastery over the mantra) bestowed the mantra to the reciter.

mantre taddevatāyāñca tathāmantrapradegurau
triṣubhaktiḥ sadākāryā sāhi prathama sādhanam

Comment: You need a son to do the agnihotra? I thought the agnihotra can be done as soon as marriage is over, since the agni that is used in the wedding is brought home and worshipped. Also, didn't Bhishma do agnihotra as a brahmachari?

Comment: You're thinking of aupAsana, not agnihotra. aupAsana is smArta-agni (1 fire). agnihotra is shrauta-agni (3 fires). All the grihya rituals (e.g. jAtakarma or shrAddha) are performed in the aupAsanAgni. All the shrauta rituals which are perfomed at home (E.g. darsha/paurNamAsa) are performed in the 3 fires. The soma and other larger shrauta sacrifices are performed in separately kindled fires  outside the home in a dedicate yAgashAla.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find more details about Agnihotra Homa which helps in purification of surroundings, cleansing of air and elimination of bacteria, viruses etc. As one answer says there are lot of incorrect videos and blogs describing Agnihotra , so I went looking for an answer in scriptures and found some information in [Asvalayana Grihya Sutra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/asvalayana-grihya-sutra/d/doc116554.html)

From Adhyaya 1 , Kandika 2

> To the deities of the **Agnihotra**, to Soma Vanaspati, to Agni and Soma, to Indra and Agni, to Heaven and Earth, to Dhanvantari, to Indra, to the Viśve devās, to Brahman.

The deities of the Agnihotra are Sûrya, Agni, and Pragâpati.

Materials required as per Adhyaya 1, Kandika 3

> 1[1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/asvalayana-grihya-sutra/d/doc116554.html). Now wherever he intends to perform a sacrifice, let him besmear (with cowdung) a surface of the dimension at least of an arrow on each side; let him draw six lines thereon, one turned to the north, to the west (of the spot on which the fire is to be placed); two (lines) turned to the east, at the two different ends (of the line mentioned first); three (lines) in the middle (of those two); let him sprinkle that (place with water), establish the (sacred) fire (thereon), put (two or three pieces of fuel) on it, wipe (the ground) round (the fire), strew (grass) round (it), to the east, to the south, to the west, to the north, ending (each time) in the north. Then (follows) silently the sprinkling (of water) round (the fire).
>
> 2. With two (Kuśa blades used as) strainers the purifying of the Ājya (is done).
>
> 3[2]. Having taken two Kuśa blades with unbroken tops, which do not bear a young shoot in them, of the measure of a span, at their two ends with his thumbs and fourth fingers, with his hands turned with the inside upwards, he purifies (the Ājya, from the west) to the east, with (the words), 'By the impulse of Savitṛ I purify thee with this uninjured purifier, with the rays of the good sun'—once with this formula, twice silently.
>
> 4[3]. The strewing (of grass) round (the fire) may be done or not done in the Ājya offerings.
>
> 5[4]. So also the two Ājya portions (may optionally be sacrificed) in the Pākayajñas.
>
> 6[5]. And the (assistance of a) Brahman (is optional), except at the sacrifice to Dhanvantari and at the sacrifice of the spit-ox (offered to Rudra).
>
> 7[6]. Let him sacrifice with (the words), 'To such and such a deity svāhā!'
>
> 8. If there is no rule (as to the deities to whom the sacrifice belongs, they are) Agni, Indra, Prajāpati, the Viśve devās, Brahman.

Assistance of a Brahmin is optional when it comes to Agnihotra. From Adhyaya 1, Kandika 3

> And the (assistance of a) Brahman (is optional), except at the sacrifice to Dhanvantari and at the sacrifice of the spit-ox (offered to Rudra).

It is to be done twice a day - around sunrise and sunset. From Adhyaya 1 Kandika 9

> 4[2]. The time for setting it in a blaze and for sacrificing in it has been explained by (the rules given with regard to) the Agnihotra,
>
> 5[3]. And the sacrificial food, except meat.
>
> 6. But if he likes he may (perform the sacrifice) with rice, barley, or sesamum.
> 7. He should sacrifice in the evening with (the formula), 'To Agni svāhā!' in the morning with (the formula), 'To Sūrya svāhā!' Silently the second (oblations) both times.

And Adhyaya 1 and Kandika 10

> 4[2]. And the deities (to whom those oblations belong), with the exception of the Upāṃśuyāja (offerings at which the formulas are repeated with low voice), and of Indra and Mahendra.
>
> 5. Other deities (may be worshipped) according to the wishes (which the sacrificer connects with his offerings).

So from above what I could gather is that in morning mantra is for Surya and Prajapati, and evening for Agni and Prajapati.

And more details on where to sit during the homa, and mantras during oblations is in Kandika 10

Comment: What A great post!! Thank You!!

Comment: @YOGANAND PATIL - You are most welcome ! However please note that thank yous, +1s etc are discouraged in comment section as per site policy. You may want to up vote answer (if not already done)